# ERROR when sending data to my KAA server

Tags: kaa

When using first kaa server application and sending data to my Kaa server from outside I get this error: CONNACK message + KAASYNC message.

My configuration for kaa server is:

```
transport host...=localhost=My PUBLIC ip
```

My config mongo on kaa server is:

```
host: MY PUBLIC IP port: 27017
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what error do you get? And how to reproduce it? It is really unclear from your question.

Comment: [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR org.kaaproject.kaa.client.channel.impl.channels.DefaultBootstrapChannel - Failed to receive operation servers list {}

Comment: and this error too: [Thread-2] INFO org.kaaproject.kaa.client.channel.impl.channels.DefaultOperationTcpChannel - Can't sync. Channel [default_operation_tcp_channel] is waiting for CONNACK message + KAASYNC message

Comment: Could you please increase logging level and upload full log of the error?

Comment: Please, increase logging level by setting -DKAA_MAX_LOG_LEVEL to 6 and send us logs.

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS WHAT I GET WHEN I COMPILE MY SDK

```
[pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.kaaproject.kaa.client.channel.failover.DefaultFailoverManager - Server [BOOTSTRAP, -1835393002] failed
[pool-2-thread-1] WARN org.kaaproject.kaa.client.channel.impl.DefaultChannelManager - Attempt to connect to the next bootstrap service will be made in 2000 ms, according to failover strategy decision
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO FirstKaaDemo - Sampled Temperature: 34
[pool-4-thread-14] INFO org.kaaproject.kaa.client.logging.strategies.RecordCountLogUploadStrategy - Need to upload logs - current count: 14, threshold: 1
[Thread-2] INFO org.kaaproject.kaa.client.channel.impl.channels.DefaultOperationTcpChannel - Can't sync. Channel [default_operation_tcp_channel] is waiting for CONNACK message + KAASYNC message
[pool-6-thread-1] INFO org.kaaproject.kaa.client.channel.impl.channels.AbstractHttpChannel - Processing sync all for channel default_bootstrap_channel
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO FirstKaaDemo - Sampled Temperature: 25
[pool-4-thread-15] INFO org.kaaproject.kaa.client.logging.strategies.RecordCountLogUploadStrategy - Need to upload logs - current count: 15, threshold: 1
[Thread-2] INFO org.kaaproject.kaa.client.channel.impl.channels.DefaultOperationTcpChannel - Can't sync. Channel [default_operation_tcp_channel] is waiting for CONNACK message + KAASYNC message
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Change Kaa Host/IP

[image: change kaa host]

To VM ip address. My case is 192.168.1.142

[image]

Step 2: Regenerate SDK and recompide and run. Done

[image]